# The applications listed on a user's apps tab are a little crowded.

Tags: feature-request

As you can see, there is a very small amount of space between each of the applications in the "apps" tab of my user profile. This makes it a little bit more difficult to read because the space between the app's description and the "remove" link is greater than the distance between adjacent apps.

[image]

Could we please have a larger margin between apps?

Comment: What is the URL for the Apps tab? I can't seem to find it. I just posted a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891046/how-do-you-see-what-applications-youve-authorized-on-stackexchange-with-oauth-a

Comment: @PaulFryer: I've [answered your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/134534/142114).